# Diagonal of a Cartesian product of cycles

Tags: graph-theory

I encountered with definition of diagonal given in the pic below:
[image]

The definition of Cartesian product is given in the pic itself.
I tried in multiple ways to draw the diagonal but I am not the getting the diagonal of length $l$ as required. Also not able to get the intuition behind this definition. Is there any connection of this with the definition of diagonal of a graph?

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider some examples. Suppose $m = 3, n=4$. Then the LCM is $12$ and the gcd is $1$. So let us see what this unique diagonal looks like. Specifically, it will be the following sequence

$$ x_{0,0}, x_{1,1}, x_{2,2}, x_{0,3}, x_{1,0}, x_{2,1}, x_{0,2}, x_{1,3}, x_{2,0}, x_{0,1}, x_{1,2}, x_{2,3} $$

Note that the next term would be $x_{0,0}$. Now for the diagonal we could have started at any $x_{0,j}$, but note that in the above diagonal, we have the point $x_{0,j}$ for all $j$. Thus, we have a unique diagonal.

How about $m = n = 3$. Now the lcm is $3$ and the gcd is three as well. So we have the following $3$ diagonals.

$$x_{0,0}, x_{1,1}, x_{2,2} \text{ and } x_{0,1}, x_{1,2}, x_{2,0} \text{ and } x_{0,2}, x_{1,0}, x_{2,0} $$

Note in each case, the last term and the first term are adjacent.

Comment: any connection with usual definition of diameter of graph?

Comment: What is relation between the symbols $x_{i,j}$’s and $d_i^j$‘s?

Comment: $d_i^j = x_{i \text{ mod }m,i+j\text{ mod }n}$